# Ruby on Rails - Activeadmin - Update model with virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

I have a activeadmin form to which allows to add a youtube URL. I validate this URL in my video model. It does works well when I want to add a new video but does nothing when I'm editing the video.
app/admin/video.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.register Media, as: 'Videos' do     
form do |f|
        f.inputs "Add youtube video" do
          f.input :category
          f.semantic_errors :error
            f.has_many :videos, allow_destroy: true do |g|
                g.input :mylink, :label => "Youtube link : ",  :type => :text
        end
        actions
        end
     end
end
```

model/video.rb :

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :media
  attr_accessor :mylink 
  YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*\z/i
  before_create :before_add_to_galerie
  before_update :before_add_to_galerie

  def before_add_to_galerie
    uid = @mylink.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
    self.uid = uid[2] if uid && uid[2]
    if self.uid.to_s.length != 11
      self.errors.add(:mylink, 'is invalid.')
      throw :abort
      false
    elsif Video.where(uid: self.uid).any?
      self.errors.add(:mylink, 'is not unique.')
      throw :abort
      false
    end
end

validates :mylink, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT
end
```

It looks like the before_update method is never triggered.
How can I make my edit work ?

EDIT :I figured out that  it is calling the before_update link for the Media model and not for the Video one.But the create is fine.

Comment: why do you think it's not triggered? Have you tried to update an existing record?

Comment: I just tried to call another method in the before_update that only print some text into the console and it does not print anything

Comment: It does work when I don't use the virtual attribute but I really need this to validate the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase the issue:

1. You have a model `Video`
2. `Video` has a virtual attribute `my_link`
3. `Video` has a `before_update` callback `before_add_to_galerie`
4. You want this callback to trigger when only `my_link` was changed

does this look correct?
If so you have 2 options, first - if you have `updated_at` change it along with `my_link`

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :my_link
  # ...
  def my_link=(val)
    return val if val == my_link
    @my_link = val
    self.updated_at = Time.zone.now
  end
end
```

or you can use [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)